# NextJS - How to disable sass preprocessing for next dev script

Tags: sass, next.js

In a NextJS project I am just styling right now. Even though I am just changing scss files, *next dev* script of course compiles everything.

Is there a way to disable the sass preprocessing, so that I can run it from my IDE without triggering the time consuming compiler? E.g. with a change in *next.config.js*?

Comment: Did you install sass? Npm i sass?

Comment: @HazratGafulov No, sass is installed system wide. I did now as you suggested it, but it does not change anything. The compoiler runs after every scss file save.